# Why does Paul use ἀνακρίνω in 1 Cor 4:3 & κρίνω in 1 Cor 4:5?

Tags: greek, word-study, 1-corinthians

(KJV)1 Corinthians 4:3

> But with me it is a very small thing that I should be judged of you, or of man's judgment: yea, I ***judge*** not mine own self.

(KJV)1 Corinthians 4:5

> Therefore ***judge*** nothing before the time, until the Lord come, who both will bring to light the hidden things of darkness, and will make manifest the counsels of the hearts: and then shall every man have praise of God.

Why does Paul use two different Greek words for JUDGE

Comment: I think you'll find this extremely helpful http://www.insearchoftruth.org/articles/word_study_judge.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to phrase the question might be, "Why does the King James Version (and most other versions) translate two different Greek words as *judge*"?

ἀνακρίνω (*anakrinō*) - at least in this context - refers to "judging" in the sense of scrutinizing,  whereas κρίνω (*krinō*) here refers to judging in a more final juridical sense.

The *Orthodox New Testament* suggests the translation:

> *But to me it is a very small thing that I should be examined by you, or by a man's day* [ανθρωπινης ημερας]*; but neither do I examine
>   myself.*
>
> *For I am conscious of nothing in myself, but not in this have I been justified; but the* One *Who examineth me is* the *Lord.*
>
> *Therefore cease judging anything before* the *time, until the Lord should come, Who both will bring to light the hidden things of
>   darkness and make manifest the counsels of the hearts; and then to
>   each one there shall be the praise of God.*

The NASB also translates ἀνακρίνω as "examine".

Comment: +1 I think what might be missing here are explanations about how ἀνα is a greek prefix, indicating "up" or "against", and used as a legal term ... in the judicial sense of ["putting someone up on trial" ... "to be be examined on a witness stand"](http://biblehub.com/greek/350.htm). 
 Evidence of this as an ancient Greek practice might help too.  Regardless, 1 Cor 4:5 carries the explicit sense of a "final verdict", only AFTER all of the extenuating circumstances/evidences are known; Examinations before this time are premature.  It seems this answer is "right", but perhaps not clear to the OP.